# wysiwyg não deixa digitar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

Estou utilizando o `wysiwyg` para criar um campo com `rich text` porém ele não está aceitando que eu digite. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Setando Javascript:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#editor').wysiwyg(); 
    });    

</script>
<script>
( function($) {    
  $(function(){
    function initToolbarBootstrapBindings() {
      var fonts = ['Serif', 'Sans', 'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Courier', 
            'Courier New', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Helvetica', 'Impact', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Tahoma', 'Times',
            'Times New Roman', 'Verdana'],
            fontTarget = $('[title=Font]').siblings('.dropdown-menu');
      $.each(fonts, function (idx, fontName) {
          fontTarget.append($('<li><a data-edit="fontName ' + fontName +'" style="font-family:\''+ fontName +'\'">'+fontName + '</a></li>'));
      });
      $('a[title]').tooltip({container:'body'});
        $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function() {return false;})
            .change(function () {$(this).parent('.dropdown-menu').siblings('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');})
        .keydown('esc', function () {this.value='';$(this).change();});

      $('[data-role=magic-overlay]').each(function () { 
        var overlay = $(this), target = $(overlay.data('target')); 
        overlay.css('opacity', 0).css('position', 'absolute').offset(target.offset()).width(target.outerWidth()).height(target.outerHeight());
      });
      if ("onwebkitspeechchange"  in document.createElement("input")) {
        var editorOffset = $('#editor').offset();
        $('#voiceBtn').css('position','absolute').offset({top: editorOffset.top, left: editorOffset.left+$('#editor').innerWidth()-35});
      } else {
        $('#voiceBtn').hide();
      }
    };
    function showErrorAlert (reason, detail) {
        var msg='';
        if (reason==='unsupported-file-type') { msg = "Unsupported format " +detail; }
        else {
            console.log("error uploading file", reason, detail);
        }
        $('<div class="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+ 
         '<strong>File upload error</strong> '+msg+' </div>').prependTo('#alerts');
    };
    initToolbarBootstrapBindings();  
    $('#editor').wysiwyg({ fileUploadError: showErrorAlert} );
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

E os campos:

```
                <div class="btn-toolbar" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font"><i class="icon-font"></i><b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font Size"><i class="icon-text-height"></i>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a data-edit="fontSize 5"><font size="5">Huge</font></a></li>
      <li><a data-edit="fontSize 3"><font size="3">Normal</font></a></li>
      <li><a data-edit="fontSize 1"><font size="1">Small</font></a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" data-edit="bold" title="Bold (Ctrl/Cmd+B)"><i class="icon-bold"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="italic" title="Italic (Ctrl/Cmd+I)"><i class="icon-italic"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="strikethrough" title="Strikethrough"><i class="icon-strikethrough"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="underline" title="Underline (Ctrl/Cmd+U)"><i class="icon-underline"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" data-edit="insertunorderedlist" title="Bullet list"><i class="icon-list-ul"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="insertorderedlist" title="Number list"><i class="icon-list-ol"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="outdent" title="Reduce indent (Shift+Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-left"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="indent" title="Indent (Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-right"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyleft" title="Align Left (Ctrl/Cmd+L)"><i class="icon-align-left"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="justifycenter" title="Center (Ctrl/Cmd+E)"><i class="icon-align-center"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyright" title="Align Right (Ctrl/Cmd+R)"><i class="icon-align-right"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyfull" title="Justify (Ctrl/Cmd+J)"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Hyperlink"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu input-append">
            <input class="span2" placeholder="URL" type="text" data-edit="createLink"/>
            <button class="btn" type="button">Add</button>
    </div>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="unlink" title="Remove Hyperlink"><i class="icon-cut"></i></a>

  </div>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" title="Insert picture (or just drag & drop)" id="pictureBtn"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a>
    <input type="file" data-role="magic-overlay" data-target="#pictureBtn" data-edit="insertImage" />
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" data-edit="undo" title="Undo (Ctrl/Cmd+Z)"><i class="icon-undo"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="redo" title="Redo (Ctrl/Cmd+Y)"><i class="icon-repeat"></i></a>
  </div>
  <input type="text" data-edit="inserttext" id="voiceBtn" x-webkit-speech="">
</div>

<div id="editor">
</div>
```

> Observações:
>   Apesar de ter inicializado o wysiwyg ele não aparece na opção inspecionar elemento >do google chrome.
>   Ja atualizei todo o projeto para o jquery mais recente.

O erro é

> Quando vou digitar na div, e tirado o foco do local aonde escreve e a opção de >centralizar o texto é acionada, não deixando escrever. Ao tentar escrever novamente, >o processo se repete.

Comment: Você está criando o componente duas vezes no código, uma no começo do código e outra no fim do document ready. Tentou remover uma das duas(de preferência de fora do document ready) ?

Comment: Como ficaria a solução ?

Comment: Como assim? Iria ficar com apenas uma chamada de `.wysiwyg()` no código, acredito eu.

Comment: Tentei porem não está funcionando ainda.

Comment: Primeiro de tudo, qual plugin você está usando; segundo: tem algum erro no seu console ?

Comment: Estou utilizando este plugin: http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ e não tem nenhum erro em meu console.

Comment: Se souber algum que possa me indicar, aceito sugestões.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues depois você da uma olhada nesse, ele  tem tradução para portugues e uma excelente documentação http://summernote.org/#/

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Mesmo com o summernote não está abrindo a caixa de texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renan,  você deve seguir uma ordem na montagem do seu `html` para carregar os componentes corretamente,

1° baixe o `jQuery`: [Download](http://jquery.com/)

E o primeiro a ser incluido, por que `bootstrap,font-awesome e summernote` usam ele.

2° baixe o `Bootstrap`: [Download](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Ele e utilizado no `font-awesome e summernote`.

3° baixe o `Font-Awesome`: [Download](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Ele e usado pelo `Summernote` para carregar os icones do editor.

4° baixe o `Summernote`: [Download](http://summernote.org/#/)

Agora você deve seguir a hierarquia na inclusão, ela pode ser feita assim:

http://jsfiddle.net/ay3cc7c9/1/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.6.9/summernote.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.6.9/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

   <body>
      <div id="summernote">Olá Mundo</div>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#summernote').summernote();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parece que esta dando conflito com o jquery que ja tenho, e so está aparecendo ola mundo.

Comment: meu jquery é jquery-1.7.2.min.js por isso está dando conflito no javascript, será que existe algum para adaptar para o meu ?

Comment: porque você não atualiza o seu jquery ? tem que ver qual e a versão que eles utilizam,eles devem possuir uma versão anterior que rode nesse jquery 1.7 porém deve apresentar alguns problemas que na versão recente foi corrigida

Comment: eles estão na `jquery-1.9.1.min.js`

Comment: o problema que se eu atualiza vai atrapalhar meu sistema todinho. nao sei porque está fazendo isto

Comment: Mais tenta me ajudar no que eu tava fazendo la em cima, não está dando para escrever, esta próximo de arruma, estou vendo se é falta de inicializar alguma coisa. Porem algo engraçado em meu projeto, é que mesmo inicializando o documento.js ele não aparece no source do google chrome, será que tem algo haver ?

Comment: se você der um click no url do seu script ele não abre o arquivo js ?

Comment: abrir abre, porem não aparece nas seleções do chrome

Comment: atualizei todo o projeto, porem ainda sim continua dando o erro de quando vou digitar ele sai do focus, e não me deixa escrever nada.